# Display flex not allowing for inline text align and styles

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, tinymce

I've made a CMS that allows users to use an editor and drag/drop images as well as text and formatting.

I have them using different templates, and my example below uses one that has a larger content area on the right half of the page, and smaller content areas on the left top and left bottom.

The images are good, but as you can see in the snippet (you have to run it and show it in full screen to see what I mean) even though my `bottomLeftContent` and `rightContent` areas have a `p` tag with `text-align: center` and right, they are both floated to the left.

Now, if I inspect the page and turn off `display:flex` for middle p, then they align properly but it messes up how my page should show (no scrolling, so the areas need to stack together the way they are.

How can I keep display flex but allow for inline p styles to work? (also, the content in the p tags is from TinyMCE editor so I can't hardcode !important or anything like that)

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.middle p{
    max-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:0;     
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    display:flex;
}

img {
    object-fit: scale-down;
    width: 100%; 
    margin:0 auto;
}

#topLeftContent{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
}

#topLeftContent img{
    object-fit: contain;
}

.topLeftContent{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.topLeftContent> img{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#bottomLeftContent{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#bottomLeftContent img{
    object-fit: contain;
}

.bottomLeftContent{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.bottomLeftContent> img{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#rightContent{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:100%;
}

#rightContent img{
    object-fit: contain;
}

.rightContent{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.rightContent> img{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.my-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100vw;
}

.my-container .top.row, 
.my-container .row.bottom {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
.my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
    background-color: #778899  ;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.my-container>.middle {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding:30px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid my-container">
        
        <div class="row top">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row" style="background-color: #778899;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row middle">
            
            <div class="col-lg-6"  >
                <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                        <div class="topLeftContent" id="topLeftContent">
                            
                            <p><img class="mySlides" src="images/Picture1.jpg" /></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row flex-center--horiz" style="height:50%; padding-top: 15px; background-color: tomato;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
                        <div class="bottomLeftContent" id="bottomLeftContent">
                            <p style="text-align: center; color: white;">SHOULD BE CENTERED</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" >
                <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent">
                    
                    <p style="text-align: right;">Paragraph over here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row middle-->
        
        <div class="row bottom">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div><h2>Ticker</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post an image of the desired layout

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the layout is actually perfect as is. However, "announcement here" should be center aligned in it's column and "Paragraph over here" should be right aligned. But they're both left aligned by default. The layout otherwise shouldn't change at all

Comment: .middle p{ display: flex; } is making the issue. Is this style really needed here?? Usually the flex property is applied to flex container. Here <p> seems to be the child element. If the flex property is meant for some other <p>, make the selector more specific so that it wont effect the other<p>

Comment: Yes, and I do know it's the issue, but it's needed because without it the columns fall into each other. I need the layout as is

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman Basically, all the content from TinyMCE is wrapped in ```p``` tags. So each content area has a display of flex but the content within each content area is within its own p tag which has display of flex. Removing the display:flex from each content area doesn't do anything. Removing from middle p works for the alignment but messes up my layout

Comment: `display: flex` does not work with `text-align`. If you want to align content inside flexbox, use `justify-content`

Comment: @Duannx Is there a way to achieve the same layout here that works with text align?

Comment: @TomN. If you want to work with `text-align` just remove `display: flex` from your p element. It might break your layout but it's the only way

Comment: @Duannx so there's nothing else to give the same layout but allow text align. The reason I've used flex is so that images can fit into each container regardless of size and scale to different display sizes